# APNS with badge in iPhone and Desktop app

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, badge

I have the mail app on both **iPhone** and **Desktop**. If I read the mail from **`desktop`** then the badge count of iPhone mail app is automatically updated (decrement of badge count) while I don not open mail on **`iPhone`**. It means my **`iPhone`** mail app is not launched yet.
How does `APNS` badge count work in these scenario?

Comment: When you read the mail from desktop,The app server get this action and send another APNS message which to change the badge

Comment: but my iOS app is in not running state / kill state. How does badge count got updated?

Comment: Check out this stack answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14256852/3278326

Comment: The server  can send APNS which contains the "badge" to set iphone`s badge.  It just like you received APNS add badge without launching App

Comment: Thanks @Dandelion

Comment: Thanks @JarvisTheAvenger

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass badge counter in the payload. see the following code.

```
{"aps":
    {"alert":"Notification Hub test notification2",
     "badge":20,
     "sound":"Default"}
}
```

See this post for more information:
[How to do badge increment on iOS push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478013/how-to-do-badge-increment-on-ios-push-notification)

[Update badge with push notification while app in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14256643/update-badge-with-push-notification-while-app-in-background)